# Font size changing buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement buttons in order to allow users to increase/decrease font size on a website.
This is the website: https://font-size-d27117.webflow.io/
I use REM everywhere, for font and for images. I'd like to change only font sizes, but not images.

I've found the script. It seems to be simple but doesn't work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#font-size-plus').on('click', function() 
{
  var fontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
  console.log(fontSize);
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) + 1;

  $('body').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px')
})

$('#font-size-minus').on('click', function() 
{
  var fontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) - 1;

  $('body').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px')
})

$('#_reset').on('click', function() {
  $('body').css('font-size', '1')
})
</script>
```

In the above script I see px instead of rems.

I tried to change PX to REM and step from 1px to 0.1rem

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#font-size-plus').on('click', function() 
{
  var fontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
  console.log(fontSize);
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) + 0.1;

  $('body').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'rem')
})

$('#font-size-minus').on('click', function() 
{
  var fontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) - 0.1;

  $('body').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'rem')
})

$('#_reset').on('click', function() {
  $('body').css('font-size', '1'  + 'rem')
})
</script>
```

None of these scripts work.

Could anyone help?

Comment: The script runs before the DOM is ready. Wait for it. Also, `parseInt` parses a string to interpret it as integer, change to `parseFloat`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+button+change+font+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main problems:

1. The event handlers aren't getting added, as the script runs immediately but the +/- button elements aren't present when it runs. The fix is to wrap your jQuery code in `$(() => { ... })`, which causes it to run only once the DOM is loaded.
2. You're setting the font size of `body`, not `html`. `rem` units are based on the *root* size, which for an HTML document is the `html` element.

There are a few other issues in your code (invalid HTML etc.), but here's a simplified version that works:

```js
$(() => {
  $('#font-size-plus').on('click', function() {
    var fontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) + 1;

    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px');
  });

  $('#font-size-minus').on('click', function() {
    var fontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize) - 1;

    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px');
  });

  $('#_reset').on('click', function() {
    $('html').css('font-size', '16px');
  });
});
```

```css
.font-16px {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.font-1rem {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.font-2rem {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.font-3rem {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<html style="font-size: 16px">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>font size</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="font-16px">
      <button id="font-size-plus">+</button>
      <button id="font-size-minus">-</button>
      <button id="_reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="font-1rem">1 rem</div>
    <div class="font-2rem">2 rem</div>
    <div class="font-3rem">3 rem</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that setting the font size on `html` affect all measurements that use `rem` values, regardless of whether they're font sizes, images, etc. You can see this difference in the `div` housing the control buttons themselves, which sets its font size in `px` instead so always remains at the same font size.

Comment: I've implemented your advice.
IT seems to work.
Final effect: https://font-size-d27117.webflow.io/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented @Lionel Rowe advice.
IT seems to work.
Final effect: font-size-d27117.webflow.io